# Замена подстроки на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать команду, которая будет из вставленного текста находить символ "- " (именно с пробелом) и стирать его до следующей буквы.
Пример: 
`На улице солн - це` -> `На улице солнце`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слегка неясно - надо искать два символа: тире и пробел (`-`), не меньше, но в примере стирается три символа: пробел, тире и обязательный пробел (`-`).

```js
let str = `На улице солн - це`;

// Удалить именно то, что нужно, самый быстрый способ, но не уберёт пробел слева,
// ибо не входит в задачу
str.replace('- ', ''); // На улице солн це // 23-25ms

// Уберёт пробел и слева, но чуть медленнее
str.replace(/ *-\ /g, ''); // На улице солнце // 54-63ms

// Как вариант для извращенцев - используя связку split + join,
// вместо специально созданного для этого Б-гом replace
str.split('- ').join(''); // На улице солн це // 186.5-188.7ms

// Странно, но split + regExp сработал быстрее
str.split(/ *- +/).join(''); // На улице солнце // 171.5-184.4ms




/*
Время по этому считалось.

Отказ:
  Делалось исключительно для поверхностного сравнения и если Вы -
   - очешуительно умелый тестер и увидели исключительно важную ошибку - 
   - просто скажите, без истерик, а то были инциденты :)

let n = Date.now(), str = `На улице солн - це`, acc = [];
for(let e = 0; e < 10; e++){
 let n = Date.now();
 for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  // Строка теста
 acc.push(Date.now() - n);
}
let info = acc.reduce((a, e) => a + e) / acc.length + 'ms';
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = 'На улице солн - це';
text.replace(/\s+-\s+/gm, '');
```

только одно но... если там ействительно тире стоит, он его сотрет

Comment: В задании сказано "именно с пробелом", поэтому, вероятно, стоит заменить `*` на `+`.